# Remember active class on reload

Tags: cookies, reload

I am creating a single page website - where the menu items change class to "active" when the user is on the current section of the page - this works out fine, but the browser "forgets" which menu-item is the current one on reload.

Is there a way to make the browser remember which element was the the last one to have the class "active", before reload?

Answer (score 0):

Use [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html).

When you mark an item as "active", save it's ID or number in *localStorage*. After loading of your page, retrieve that information and mark corresponding item.

Answer (score 0):

When the user is on the specific section of the page - set to the cookie: `section=idOfTheSection`
And add javascript function that on-load checks the cookie and set the right class to 'active'.

Comment: You wrote 'where the menu items change class to "active" when the user is on the current section of the page - this works out fine'. so, add there script that change the cookie to point on this section.